# Meaning/Translation: 熟肉 [TV Series]

Tags: translation, meaning, meaning-in-context

I've seen the word `熟肉` associated with TV Series'.

For example:

[image: 熟肉]

- What does it mean?
- What's a *good* English translation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be file sharing jargon.

熟肉 means the video **has Chinese subtitles**. This is in contrast to 生肉 (raw meat), which means the video has no Chinese subtitles, that it is in its original format. I guess the meanings allude to the fact that meat is usually consumed cooked, and that if it is raw (has no subtitles), it cannot be consumed easily. Why use this specific analogy I have no idea; jargon can often have strange origins.

Likewise, for jargon it is hard to find good references for them. There is a blog post here which defines the term in a footnote:

- https://catalyst.uw.edu/gopost/conversation/swelland/334740

And a Baidu Zhidao (similar to Yahoo Answers) question here:

- http://zhidao.baidu.com/question/203271518.html